# What is Quantum Cosmology

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, cosmology

I understand that quantum behavior is only apparent on the microscopic level, what then is the subject of Quantum Cosmology?

Comment: Cosmology in general is a discipline that studies the universe all along its lifetime. As it is now assumed that the universe started to exist with the big-bang, the universe was  so small short moments after the big-bang that quantum effects played an important role. There are certainly other examples that demonstrate that Quantum cosmology is important to consider.

Answer (score 3):

During the first moments of the big bang, the universe was at submicroscopic scale- where quantum effects are important. This means that to understand what was going on at the earliest times, you have to understand quantum effects.

Since the universe we inhabit now grew from those earliest times, its initial conditions (established by quantum effects) will affect what we currently see around us.

The quantum cosmology program involves understanding the effects that the quantum initial conditions had on the subsequent evolution of the universe, and why our universe is the way it is at the present time.

Comment: “The universe was at submicroscopic scale” actually means “the radius of curvature of the universe was submicroscopic”. The universe might well have been (and still be) infinite in size, but it was once highly curved in the sense of spacetime curvature.

Comment: Why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Because it would be basically the same as yours (which I upvoted). I wasn’t trying to criticize your answer. I was just adding a minor detail.

Comment: but yours furnishes more insight. I had never considered the curvature argument before, and it is cool.

Comment: It's probably not worth a "ping", but, what I can't understand is how submicroscopic considerations stay in the realm of physics, at least if "submicroscopic" is broadly interpreted as "observable only thru magnification energies sufficient to collapse the object being examined into a microscopic black hole", or "requiring magnification energies exceeding those in our observable region". (If it's interpreted as requiring an electron microscope instead of one focusing the trajectories of photons, I guess it stays physical.)  Maybe that's why quantum gravity keeps receding into the future.

Comment: @Edouard, in my answer I used the term submicroscopic to indicate things that exist on extremely small distance scales. Note that the interior of a proton can be observed, using an electron microscope with a 10,000 foot long beam tube (SLAC), and no black holes result.